# Magento: Using it as general purpose FrameWork/CMS (BareBone Magento)

Tags: magento

I'm sure I'm not the first thinking that but ...

1. It is possible to use magento as FrameWork ? ( for sure yes )
2. why I should not ?
3. What module should I disable what I should not ?
4. **how can I hack the installer** to install only some module ( it enough disable them /etc/modules/ ... )?

The idea is to use layout/template and MVC Magento as base for another app.

---

**Update**:
the idea is to reuse Magento Architecture for other purpose that Shopping Cart:

1. Writing new module for new functionality.
2. Removing module that I don't need

The focus of the question is:

1. **Which module can I remove** to have a kind of BareBone Magento ? ( just backend and frontend with layout/template + CMS )
2. There is **any way to hack the installer** to avoid table creation ?

Comment: Have updated the answer with the link to Magento Lite - that should answer the question for you.

Comment: thank you is exactly what I meant !!!
I was almost sure that my idea it is not so original :)

Comment: Lol, it's a great idea - and the fact that some kind developer already thought of it, customised the framework, packaged it up and put it on github makes it an even better idea!!

Comment: I wonder why @Alan Storm it is not involved in this stuff ?)

Comment: Did you add any experience with Magento Lite ? My biggest concern is about performance ! any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with both Vinci and pspahn. I would have thought Magento would make a pretty dreadful general purpose CMS. However twice this year I have been commissioned to do just that, two Magento sites with no e-commerce at all.

Their reasoning was that they viewed it as a much more secure, powerful enterprise grade platform than some other open source CMS. It also left open the possibility of easily adding serious e-commerce (as opposed to limitation riddled plugins) if/when they started selling online.

You've also got very good user account management functionality built in there to, APIs, automated backups...when you think about it there's loads of goodies.

And +1 for Fishpig's module, that just gets better and better.

**EDIT**

Have a look at Magento Lite, that's what you are looking for;

https://github.com/colinmollenhour/magento-lite

Answer (score 4):

I will second Vinci's answer. The "CMS" features of Magento are functional at best. It is really a terrible CMS if you want to, you know, manage content.

Enterprise has some additional features on the CMS side, but it's still not enough to warrant it being a proper CMS.

Of course, it can certainly be extended and custom widgets can be built that will give it a more user friendly, client-proof type of site (where they can simply fill out a form to populate a page). This is more labor, and it ultimately works, but it's easier to use Expression Engine or another proper CMS.

The Fishpig extension for Magento that integrates Wordpress also works pretty well if you would like to go that route.

On the contrary to Vinci's comment that it would be difficult to use for something other than eCommerce, this is not entirely true. The Category/Product models could be easily repurposed to other concepts, especially considering that Magento supports virtual products.

You could easily use this to build, say, an online learning center where "products" are simply virtual products with some documents/videos/etc attached. Or you could turn off the shopping cart/add-cart/etc and go into what PrestaShop calls "Catalog Mode" where nothing is available for purchase, but you still have a library of items. I've done this with my family's tree nursery business where the site is essentially a catalog of plants along with tons of attributes and sorting and such. Search by climate zone, mature height, etc.

At least several times a week I think of a new idea that could be built with Magento, but that does not necessarily mean it is an eCommerce site.

Comment: this is the point once you learn how magento works you have this question "why should not use this Architectur for something else ? "

Answer (score 2):

Using Magento as a Framework / CMS would be an overkill and to tell the truth Magento doesnt have great CMS features. If you really want a CMS / framework go for Drupal or Modx.
Magento is still a very eCommerce application at its core and it would be difficult to use it for anything else other than an eCommerce site

Comment: You probably miss understood me: I don't care about CMS limitation, as far as I can write my own module to manage them and as far as I can integrate Wordpress in Magento. My idea is to reuse magento Architecture for other purpose than a shopping cart.

Answer (score 0):

i recently met the sales rep for this company http://www.tangora.com/CMS.1580.aspx
he say's the company does well with large clients because they have a powerful basic cms and are able to deliver on cutomer needs.

however they seem to charge for functionality as saas even if you request something custom built for you and have "secretive" practices.

i thought while talking to the guy that magento would be better for these large companies because they'd have a greater flexiblity when choosing developers and over how they pay for the product etc.

also maybe you should watch this video he talks about coupling in magento 1 and 2 as well as its impacts
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Db7BW_RZ_0o